# iOS SKStore: Cache product results

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

SKStore takes several seconds to query the list of products from Apple's servers. Currently an in-app purchase isn't possible in my app until the request is finished. But I don't want to turn away a customer who's ready to buy.

Is it possible to store the results from didReceiveResponse? Then I could load them when the app is re-started (and overwrite them with fresh data when didReceiveResponse comes it).

I tried storing the products NSArray in NSUserDefaults, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you can be more specific as to why the `NSUserDefaults` approach didn't work. I don't know about IAP specifically, but your approach doesn't seem incorrect to me at least.

Comment: "Why" is difficult to say. It just doesn't seem to load the data. I changed the approach and stored the individual strings instead of the entire array. And that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the approach and stored the individual strings instead of the entire array. And that worked. The user can now buy immediately after starting the app.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't take that long to query your IAP products from Apple, depending on your Internet connection.  If you are going to have a number of IAP products that may take some time to be queried, I recommend you to use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) to show your users that there is some processing that is being done in the background.

Comment: Long is relative. Without WiFi (and in a small town without a high speed network) my iPhone takes about 10 seconds (after the app started) until it's ready to buy.